# Uncaught IntegrationError: Invalid stripe.redirectToCheckout parameter: items.0.price is not an accepted parameter

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, jsx

My goal is to use react front end to setup a stripe checkout using node. I mapped the apiId using the key prop to iterate over all the items in my list. But there is an integration warning inside the console and I'm not sure why. I've added the js.stripe script src into my html file so I don't understand why an API call is not being made.

```
 function checkout() {
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            items: items.map(item => ({
                quantity: item.quantity,
                price: item.apiId
            })),
            successUrl: "https://www.website.com/success",
            cancelUrl: "https://www.website.com/canceled",
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Quanity</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {items.map((item) => (
                        <tr key={item.apiId}>
                            <td>{item.name}</td>
                            <td>
                                <img
                                    src={`/images/${item.apiId}.jpg`}
                                    alt={item.name}
                                    width={180}
                                />
                            </td>
                            <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                            <td>{formatPrice(item.price)}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                    <tr>
                        <td style={{ textAlign: "right" }} colSpan={3}>
                            Total:
            </td>
                        <td>{formatPrice(totalPrice(items))}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style={{ textAlign: "right" }} colSpan={4}>
                            <button onClick={checkout}>Complete checkout</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `items` field only accepts an array of SKU/Plans and a quantity. If you're using Prices you want to use `lineItems`: https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout#stripe_checkout_redirect_to_checkout-options-lineItems

Comment: I want to integrate stripe checkout into react, using jsx files. If I use this method I would have to hard code each item in my array, rather than using a {key} token to map the items of the array.

Comment: Not sure why you think that. You just need to change your redirect code to say `lineItems: items.map(item => { ...` and it should work as you expect.