# stripe.redirectToCheckout parameter: price is not an accepted parameter react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I have an error I am running into on my stripe checkout in react... I have a button and when it is clicked, it is supposed to redirect to the stripe checkout page. However, I get the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid stripe.redirectToCheckout parameter: price is not an accepted parameter.
```

this happens when I run this code -- this is my entire checkout.js page

```
 import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import getStripe from './stripe';

const firestore = firebase.firestore();


export async function createCheckoutSession(){

    // without uid
    
    // return firestore.collection()
    const checkoutSessionRef =  await firestore.collection('profiledata').doc().collection('checkout_sessions').add(
        
        // {price : 'price_1IGEdTKDPaWWeL1ymwWH5Ubb',
        {price : '9.99',
         success_url : window.location.origin,
        //  cancel_url: window.location.origin,
    }
    );
    
    console.log("Before onSnapShot");
    checkoutSessionRef.onSnapshot(async (snap) => {
        const sessionid = snap.data();
        console.log("Snap Data: ", snap.data());
        console.log("Session ID: ", sessionid);
        if (sessionid) {
            console.log("Inside session ID: ", sessionid);
            const stripe = loadStripe("pk_test_mystripeid")
             stripe.redirectToCheckout(sessionid)
        }
});
}
```

does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Don't. repost the same question multiple times please. At best it'll get closed, but it may get you banned from the site.

Comment: didn't realize this :( just trying to get an answer for my issues. do you have any ideas of what is happening?

Comment: The error message seems to pop up regularly: https://www.google.com/search?q=Invalid+stripe.redirectToCheckout+parameter%3A+price+is+not+an+accepted+parameter. The answer to this question seems promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446565/uncaught-integrationerror-invalid-stripe-redirecttocheckout-parameter-items-0

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Checkout Session, [`line_items.price`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price) is a Price ID in the form of `price_123`, not an integer.

What is `sessionid` in this context? Is it a string or an object? Since you're using sessions it should be a string in the form of `cs_test_123`. What do your console.log's output? On what line is the error happening?

`stripe.redirectToCheckout` is an asynchronous method, but you're not catching any errors. Try something like this instead:

```
const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  sessionId: session.id,
});

if (result.error) {
  // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
  // error, display the localized error message to your customer
  // using `result.error.message`.
}
```

You also don't appear to be using `loadStripe` correctly, as it's also an asynchronous method that returns a promise: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#loadstripe.

There's a lot going on here and not much info (for instance, what does `getStripe` do?). I suggest you take some time to read the react-stripe-js docs to familiarise yourself with the library and how to use it: https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js